# The matrix indexing outputs of x(:) and x(1:end) are different

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

The following is test code and their matrix indexing outputs respectively. Aren't `x(:)` and `x(1:end)` the same thing in MATLAB? 
Why are their outputs different?

```
>>x = [1 2 3;4 5 6]
x =
     1     2     3
     4     5     6
>> xx = x(:)
xx =
     1
     4
     2
     5
     3
     6
>> xx = x(1:end)
xx =
     1     4     2     5     3     6
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many different ways to index in MATLAB. This question deals with two of those modes. In short, `x(:)` is not a short-cut to `x(1:end)`.

`x(1:end)` is equivalent to `x(1:numel(x))`, which in this case is `x(1:6)`. `p=1:6` is a row vector with indices. Here we are telling MATLAB to create a new row vector where each element `i` corresponds to `x(p(i))`. Doing `x((1:6).')` will yield a column vector, because the indexing array is a column vector. `x([1,2;3,4;5,6])` will yield a 3x2 matrix, because the indexing array is a 3x2 matrix.

`x(:)` tells MATLAB to reshape the array `x` into a column vector. It is equivalent to `reshape(x,[],1)`.